# fleetctl load hello.service hangs

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, coreos

When loading the hello.service from the [coreos quickstart](https://coreos.com/docs/quickstart/).
Am running on amazon ec2.

The command hangs.

```
Last login: Fri Sep 12 18:47:20 2014 from 10.0.11.90
CoreOS (alpha)
core@ip-10-32-252-148 ~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME=CoreOS
ID=coreos
VERSION=435.0.0
VERSION_ID=435.0.0
BUILD_ID=
PRETTY_NAME="CoreOS 435.0.0"
ANSI_COLOR="1;32"
HOME_URL="https://coreos.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues"
core@ip-10-32-252-148 ~ $ fleetctl list-machines
MACHINE     IP      METADATA
2be4e7f1... 10.32.252.144   -
73477fd7... 10.32.252.147   -
87abdeb3... 10.32.252.145   -
adc91c39... 10.32.252.148   -
core@ip-10-32-252-148 ~ $ fleetctl list-units   
UNIT    MACHINE ACTIVE  SUB
core@ip-10-32-252-148 ~ $ fleetctl load hello.service
```

Here's the [user-data](https://gist.github.com/joshuacalloway/d12fc032554e79b47267) that I used for amazon ec2.

Comment: I do not understand your question, please be more specific and describe the situation.

Comment: For some reason, I am not able to get fleet to launch simple services on amazon EC2 cluster of alpha coreos.

Comment: I got this to work.  I updated the user-data that I used.